# Javascript Oscillation

Tags: javascript, animation

I have this following animation:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.example_path {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 530px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
}

.example_path .example_block {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
<script>
function move(elem) {

  var left = 0

  function frame() {

    left+=10  // update parameters 

    elem.style.left = left + 'mm' // show frame 

    if (left == 10000)  // check finish condition
      clearInterval(id)
  }

  var id = setInterval(frame, 1) // draw every 1ms
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div onclick="move(this.children[0])" class="example_path">
    <div class="example_block"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

as you see, the blue block moves out of the rectangle if it crosses it. how do i have the blue block oscillate about the rectangular border to and fro keeping the speed constant throughout ...

(in my case the speed is 10 m/s aka 10 mm/ms)

Comment: please add some more details, what you need from this code?

Comment: did you copy the code and paste it in a text editor, just try that and tell me what happens? The block crosses the right border right? @ZaheerAhmed

Comment: Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5y6w/) of the problem. I'd suggest adding one for future questions

Comment: Since CSS3 this functionality was moved from javascript to animation property - you should have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update code as: [Here is working JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XhAS9/2/)

```
function move(elem) {

        var left = 0
        var fwdMove = true;

        function frame() {
            if (left < 0) {
                fwdMove = true;
            } else if (left > 520) {
                fwdMove = false;
            }

            fwdMove?left += 10:left -= 10
            elem.style.left = left + 'px' // show frame
        }    
        var id = setInterval(frame, 1) // draw every 1ms
    }
```

Comment: Yup, brilliant, thanks a lot, you surely deserve an accept! and a plus vote!

Comment: can you please tell me the same thing in millimeters and not in seconds, i tried replacing the px with mm but the block stops somewhere outside

Answer (score 0):

We begin by adding a variable to track the direction that we're heading in. We don't want to modify how fast you're moving, so we use a positive or negative 1 to affect the position.

```
var direction = 1; // 1=Right, -1=Left
var left = 0

function frame() {
    left+=(10 * direction);  // update parameters
```

Because mm are a print-unit, and we're working in the browser, we'll change it to use px. If you really need to use mm, you'll have to find a way of converting between them for the box to stop at the appropriate spot.

```
elem.style.left = left + 'px' // show frame
```

Finally, we check whether we've gone past the bounds of the box, and if so, we put it back in the box and reverse the direction;

```
if (left <= 0) {
    direction = 1; // Begin moving to the left
    left = 0; // Put the box back in the path
} else if (left >= (530 - 20)) {
    direction = -1; // Begin moving to the right
    left = (530 - 20); // Put the box back in the path
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5y6w/1/).